# Appending a html file to JSDOM in mocha test file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, jsdom

Is that possible to append a html file to Jsdom which already been loaded with a seperate html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. The simplest approach would be to:

1. Create your initial DOM with `jsdom`.
2. Read in the second HTML file to a string using `fs`.
3. Append the contents of the second HTML file to the original DOM returned by `jsdom`.

Install

```
npm install jsdom --save-dev
npm install fs --save-dev
```

Example code:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
var fs = require('fs');
var document = (new jsdom('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>')).window.document;
var secondHtml = fs.readFileSync('HelloWorld.html').toString();
document.body.innerHTML = secondHtml;
```

Note that your second HTML should exclude `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. Otherwise you'll have problems with a `<body>` tag inserted inside an existing `<body>` tag.

Comment: i need to bind two html using jsdom.fromfile(), what to do for that?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers *replace* the body's inner html. The OP wants to *append*:

Dependencies:

```
npm install jsdom
```

Solution:

```
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");
const fs      = require("fs");

const appendJSDOM = (dom, htmlFile) => {
    const html = fs.readFileSync(htmlFile).toString();
    dom.window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

JSDOM.fromFile("file1.html")
.then(dom => {
    appendJSDOM(dom ,"file2.html");
    console.log(dom.serialize());
});
```

You can keep calling `appendJSDOM()` to append more html files. But like the other answers have said you should omit the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags in the additional html files.

[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) can also insert HTML in different places depending on what you put as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will help.

```
require('jsdom-global')();
var fs = require('fs');
document = window.document;
var dashboard = 
fs.readFileSync('yourHtmlFile').toString();
document.documentElement.innerHTML  = dashboard;
```